# Azure Portal - Browser based Command line interface hang

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azure-cloud-shell

I am using browser-based Azure CLI for creating managed app definition for my azure managed application. Previously I was using a storage account for the CLI which I just deleted because I realized that it has no use other than azure CLI and I wanted to use the storage account with resources in. Now, after deleting that storage account, I am unable to use browser-based Azure CLI as it goes to hang state.

Is there a way to switch storage account for the browser-based azure cli at this stage?
Or Any other way to get out of this hang state?

I already tried:
1. azure cli restart (using 'power' button and 'close' plus relaunch 'cli')
2. re-login
3. another browser, incognito, etc
4. another system

[image: Browser-Based Azure CLI - Image]

Comment: You may close and re-open the Azure Portal and then check to see if that makes any difference. Or Sign out and re-login to the Azure Portal and then try.
Also, test this on another browser or private mode and see if that helps.

Comment: use standard troubleshooting: another browser, another pc, incognito mode, just like @Ashok said

Comment: i already did all this. but still facing the problem

Comment: Are you still hitting this issue? When deleting your storage account it should reset the state of cloud shell for you and retrigger the onboarding dialogues